# transparent point plot does not work

Tags: gnuplot, transparency, scatter-plot

I use GNUPLOT to plot scatter-data. My aim is plotting them with transparent vision. My code at gnuplot is:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
pl "myfile.txt" fs solid 1.0 u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.7
```

The gnuplot does not recognize fs.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `plot "myfile.txt" fillstyle solid...`?

Comment: @vaettchen yes, it also does not work! the Gnuplot does not recognize fillstyle.  It shows ; behind it! (error:   ; expected)